# Image to take shape of div (CSS3)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using CSS3 borders to create shapes that users can then drag images onto it.

The problem is, I'd like the image to take the shape of the div.

Can this be done with CSS or would I need to do this using jQuery?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
 <div class="my-div">
     <img class="div-image" src="image.jpg" />
 </div>

 border-left: 300px solid red;
 border-right: 200px solid transparent;
 border-top: 30px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
```

This creates a box with slanted sides in the shape i want the image to be

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rcpzd/)

Comment: you mean you want to resize the images? why not set them as backgroundimage via jquery and set backgroundrepeat to false?

Comment: Do you have any code? Also  - I see no why you may need a jquery. Except if that should not be done dynamically. But in any case, CSS should be completely enough here.

Comment: You can see what I'm after in my question and the link to jsFiddle

Comment: The reason the JSFiddle doesn't work is because the shape you're seeing with the grey background is made up of the borders. Box borders are displayed on top of box content. In your case, the box borders take up the entirety of the box itself,so your grey borders are all you get to see. The image is loaded but hidden behind the box. I'll repeat what I said in my answer: CSS Shapes are not a good solution for anything other than simple hacks. Use SVG if you want a robust solution.

Comment: Do you know how I'd do it using SVG? I don't really want to have x/y co-orders for each point though. thats why i used the border on the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is using CSS borders to hack shapes.

If you want to do what you're asking, you need to be using a better solution -- ie create shapes using real graphics (probably SVG or Canvas) rather than faking it in CSS. CSS shapes are very limited, and only really useful for showing off the fact the CSS can do them at all. They're not really much use in practice.

My suggestion would be SVG. SVG is a vector graphics format that can be embedded in an HTML page, and would be a far better solution to your question. You can easily create an element of any shape you want, and fill it with an image. The only down-side of SVG is that it isn't supported by older browsers (IE8, for example), but this can easily be worked around, as IE8 supports an alternative format called VML. Several Javascript libraries exist that will work with either SVG or VML

I recommend you look up a library called [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). See the examples on their site for some of the things you can do. It's all really pretty easy. You will need to learn some new syntax, but once you've got the basics, you'll be amazed at what you can achieve.

[EDIT]
I've just seen your edit to the question with the JSFiddle example of what you're trying to do.

The reason the JSFiddle doesn't work is because the shape you're seeing with the grey background is made up of the borders. Box borders are displayed on top of box content. In your case, the box borders take up the entirety of the box itself,so your grey borders are all you get to see. The image is loaded but hidden behind the box. I'll repeat what I said originally: CSS Shapes are not a good solution for anything other than simple hacks. Use SVG if you want a robust solution.

Comment: @Danield - uh, yes. yes I do. (not enough caffeine yet this morning for me, I guess....)

Comment: @Danield - btw, please feel free to edit stuff here if it's got obvious mistaked like that. editing is encouraged.

Comment: The main issue I have is how to store the values in a database. I currently have a bunch of rows with height/width/position (x, y) that when i loop through, crate a bunch of boxes to the user.

Comment: @SDC Have you implemented drag and drop using Raphael?

Comment: @user: yes, although not in quite the context you're describing; I've implemented a system that includes draggable elements for the user to define shapes, etc. I haven't done dragging+dropping external elements into the raphael element. However, it responds to standard DOM events, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to set the image to 100% width inside the div.

Example:

```
<div class="new-shape">(image)</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.new-shape img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[class=my-div]").css({  "position": "absolute",
        "top": "300px",
        "left": "200px",
        "display": "block",
        "width": "500px"
    });
```